# JDO in Google App Engine: How should polymorphic relationships be implemented?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, jdo

I'm working on GAE-based applications, which uses JDO to access datastore. I need to implement polymorphic relationship between persisted objects.

There's abstract parent class:

```
@PersistenceCapable
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceStrategy.SUBCLASS_TABLE)
public abstract class Parent {
 @PrimaryKey
 @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
 @Extension(vendorName = "datanucleus", key = "gae.encoded-pk", value = "true")
 String id;

    // ....
```

And several child classes:

```
@PersistenceCapable (identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION)
public class Child extends Parent {

    // ....
```

Also, there's one more class, which should have reference to one of child classes. According to ["Polymorphic Relationships" section of "Entity Relationships in JDO" article](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/relationships.html#Polymorphic_Relationships), the best way to implement such relationship is to store key of an object, so this class looks in the following way:

```
@PersistenceCapable (identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION)
public class OtherClass {

    @Persistent
    private String reference;

    // ....
```

I retrieve string key of referenced object from instance of OtherClass. Then I would like to obtain referenced object itself: it's an instance of one of Parent subclasses. BUT:

- If I do it with [pm.getObjectById(oid)](http://db.apache.org/jdo/api20/apidocs/javax/jdo/PersistenceManager.html#getObjectById%28java.lang.Object%29) method:

  Object object = pm.getObjectById(reference);

JDOObjectNotFoundException exception is thrown (*javax.jdo.JDOObjectNotFoundException: No such object FailedObject:...*).

- If I do it with [getObjectById(class, key)](http://db.apache.org/jdo/api20/apidocs/javax/jdo/PersistenceManager.html#getObjectById%28java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.Object%29) method:

  Parent object = pm.getObjectById(Parent.class, reference);

FatalNucleusUserException exception is thrown (*org.datanucleus.store.appengine.FatalNucleusUserException: Received a request to find an object of kind Parent but the provided identifier is the String representation of a Key for kind Child*)

What is correct way to retrieve instance of one of subclasses referenced in another entity?

**UPDATE**: I found [this](https://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine-java/browse_thread/thread/193fa626dd3f4072) thread in GAE google group, but frankly it did not help me a lot.

Comment: Since currently there's no polymorphism support, I made a workaround - store additional information about type of referenced object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

App Engine's JDO layer doesn't currently support polymorphism. In fact, I'm not sure if JDO supports it in general or not.

Answer (score 1):

I found the same problem with JDO and App Engine, so I started a project that implements a workaround for this. https://code.google.com/p/datanucleus-appengine-patch/
My first test with the code I have now looks okay, feel free to try it out at give me some feedback.

Actually my workaround may solve your problem 2 ways.

1. I implemented a getObjectById(class, id) that also looks for kinds that are instances of the provided class.
2. I implemented a getObjectById(oid) that does some special handling of lookup if oid is of type com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Key, then it will figure out the correct class to return.
3. I added a new annotation @PolymorphicRelationship that will make is easy to handle to workaround that App Engine describes, with storing the keys. Sample shown below:

> ```
>  @Persist
>  public Collection<Key> myChildKeys;
>
>  @NotPersistent
>  @PolymorphicRelationship(keyField ="myChildKeys")
>  public Collection<TestChild> myChildren;
> ```

Comment: Thank you, currently I'm investigating datanucleus-appengine-patch.

Comment: Please let me know what you think. This is my first draft of an idea of a workaround for that problem. I right now strugeling with the unittest setup of the project

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this rather cancerous and smelly anti-pattern to get around this limitation of JDO/App Engine.

```
@JsonIgnore
@Persistent(mappedBy="account")
private List<XProvider> xProviders;

@JsonIgnore
@Persistent(mappedBy="account")
private List<YProvider> yProviders;

// TODO: add extra providers here and in getProviders() below...
```

And then to get the collection:

```
public List<XProvider> getXProviders() {
    if (xProviders == null) {
        xProviders = new ArrayList<XProvider>();
    }
    return xProviders;
}
//etc with other getters and setters for each collection.

public List<Provider> getProviders() {

    List<Provider> allProviders = new ArrayList<Provider>();

    // TODO: add extra providers here...
    allProviders.addAll(getXProviders());
    allProviders.addAll(getYProviders());

    return allProviders;
}
```

It's a bad solution, but *any port in a storm*...

(Also relates a little to this bug, using interfaces as the collection type http://code.google.com/p/datanucleus-appengine/issues/detail?id=207)